# Latex, NO section number in TOC but visible in the actual section heading

Tags: latex

I am writing a document where I do not want subsection numbering to show in the TOC (I want the subsection heading visible in the TOC) but I want the subsection numbering to show in the actual document heading.

This is what I want

```
Table of Contents
1. Chapter One
 1.1 Section One
       SubSection One

Chapter 1
Chapter One
Some chapter text

1.1 Section One
Some text

1.1.1 Subsection One
Some text
```

I tried using \setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} but this removes the number even from the section heading so what I have is,

```
Table of Contents
1. Chapter One
 1.1 Section One
       SubSection One

Chapter 1
Chapter One
Some chapter text

1.1 Section One
Some text

Subsection One
Some text
```

Is it possible to get the section number in the document heading but not in the TOC entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a latex example (using the "article" class), I get this in the .toc file:

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}test section without number}{1}{section.1}
```

The important part here is the `\numberline` macro. Redefining it to something empty like

```
\def\numberline#1{}
```

will remove all numberings in the toc and not elsewhere.
If you get something like `\tocsubsection` instead in the .toc (see other answer), then you can probably do something like:

```
\let\oldtocsubsection=\tocsubsection
\def\tocsubsection#1#2#3{\oldtocsubsection{#1}{}{#3}}
```

However, this removes *all* numbers in the table of contents. If you want to control at which level the numbering disappear, the `\contentsline` macro expands to different macros depending on the context, e.g., `\l@section`. Those macros in turn use the generic `\@dottedtocline` macro. This is the one you need to modify, in which we will conditionally redefine `\numberline`.

To have control on the depth at which to stop displaying numbers, let us define a new counter:

```
\newcounter{sectocnonumdepth}
\setcounter{sectocnonumdepth}{2}
```

Then the conditional redefinition will be following line (extracted from the code for more readability).

```
 \ifnum #1>\c@sectocnonumdepth \def\numberline##1{}\fi%
```

I simply copy-pasted the definition of `\@dottedtocline` from the `latex.ltx` source file, and added the check inside. Here is the code for the whole example:

```
\newcounter{sectocnonumdepth}
\setcounter{sectocnonumdepth}{2}


\makeatletter
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\ifnum #1>\c@sectocnonumdepth \def\numberline##1{}\fi%
     \leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Final note: this will make the title of section and subsection to start at the same horizontal position, since there is no number to display. If you want more padding, you can for instance add `\quad` to the new definition of `\numberline`, or to even use the original definition with just the `#1` removed:

```
\def\numberline##1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil}}
```

Comment: I'd just like to say that this was remarkably helpful to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of a programmatic way of doing this, but I do know that you can go into the generated *.toc file for your document and remove the section number argument for the section that you want to suppress.

You can change this:

```
\contentsline {subsection}{\tocsubsection {}{1.1}{subsection one}}{1}
```

To this:

```
\contentsline {subsection}{\tocsubsection {}{}{subsection one}}{1}
```

Which will generate what you want.  Watch out, this gets regenerated each time you compile your tex source.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this as back up, if there isn't any programmtic way.

Comment: Although you do need to build output once after you make the change in .toc file to see the effects of the changes.

Comment: I'm sorry i had to change my accepted answer. Sparshong's works really well and is done quite cleanly in a programmatic way. But until then yours worked as a quick fix very well too!